# TextBox e botão dinâmico C# + ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, controles

Estou alimentando um webform com textboxes e botões a partir de um repeater, de acordo com as tuplas(tabela pessoas) retornadas em uma consulta SQL, vinculando o código a atributos específicos dentro desses controles. Para os textbox estou utilizando o atributo hidden, enquanto para os botões estou utilizando o atributo CommandArgument, a fim de utilizá-lo com o método OnCommand. Agora preciso que no método OnCommand ele identifique qual o textbox(atributo hidden) corresponde ao CommandArgument vinculado para que eu possa efetuar inserção das informações em minha base de dados. Existe alguma maneira de fazer essa verificação ou até mesmo uma maneira mais fácil de atingir esse meu objetivo?

Meu repeater:

```
<div class="col-md-6" runat="server">
     <asp:Repeater ID="rptControles" runat="server">
          <ItemTemplate>
               <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                         <div class="form-group">
                              <div id="formulario" class="input-group" runat="server">
                                   <asp:TextBox ID="txtURL" class="form-control" hidden='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "pes_codigo") %>' placeholder='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "pes_nome") %>' runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                   <span class="input-group-btn">
                                        <asp:Button ID="btnValidar" CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "pes_codigo") %>' OnCommand="btnValidar_Command" CssClass="btn btn-default" runat="server" Text="Go!" CausesValidation="false" />
                                   </span>
                              </div>
                         </div>
                    </div>
               </div>
          </ItemTemplate>
     </asp:Repeater>
 </div>
```

Page_Load:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    populaFormulario(Convert.ToInt32(Session["codigo_evento"]));
}
```

populaFormulario:

```
public void populaFormulario(int codigoEvento)
{
    ParticipanteDB parDB = new ParticipanteDB();

    rptControles.DataSource = parDB.SelecionarParticipantes(codigoEvento).Tables[0].DefaultView;
    rptControles.DataBind();
}
```

btnValidar_Command:

```
protected void btnValidar_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    var button = (Button)sender;

    var textbox = (TextBox)button.Parent.FindControl("txtURL");

    TextBox1.Text = e.CommandArgument.ToString() + " - " + textbox.Text;
}
```

Exemplo de retorno dos textboxes e buttons:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você pode utilizar JS? Pois se puder, você então tem a oportunidade de fazer a chamada de um método em que valide sua função, podendo até ser assincrona. Com o javascript ficará mais fácil de encontrar o textbox que você quer. Porém com o C# no codebehind é possível também.

Comment: Claro, poderia ser em JS sim, porém, ainda sou novato em JS e não tenho a mínima ideia de como faria pra desenvolver uma função que satisfaça esse meu objetivo. Conseguiria criar a função para verificar os controles que tem o mesmo valor de atributo, mas não saberia como lidar com a inserção no banco de dados após a recuperação dessa função, tendo em vista que realizo toda a inserção no botão no codebehind. Como faria isso?

Answer (score 1):

Como seu CommandArgument tem o mesmo valor do atributo hidden do textbox, aproveite e use o próprio CommandArgument, que é enviado no CommandEventArgs.

EDIT : Como você quer o valor do TextBox referente ao botão, pode então usar a propriedade Parent do sender (no caso seu botão). O parent será a sua div formulario. Uma vez acessando essa div, usamos o método FindControl para buscar um controle chamado txtUrl. Lembrando de fazer os devidos casts, segue abaixo o exemplo :

```
   using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.UI;
    using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

    namespace WebApplication3
    {
        public partial class _Default : Page
        {
            protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
#region Só um exemplo
                var tabela = new DataTable();
                tabela.Columns.Add(new DataColumn { ColumnName = "pes_codigo" });
                tabela.Columns.Add(new DataColumn { ColumnName = "pes_nome" });

                tabela.Rows.Add("1", "João");
                tabela.Rows.Add("2", "Paulo");
                tabela.Rows.Add("3", "Pedro");
                tabela.Rows.Add("4", "Mateus");

                rptControles.DataSource = tabela;
                rptControles.DataBind();
#endregion
            }

            protected void btnValidar_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
            {
                var button = (Button)sender;//Pegamos o botão.

                var textbox = (TextBox)button.Parent.FindControl("txtUrl");//button.Parent é a div id= formulário, logo iremos procurar o textbox txtUrl nessa Div.

                Response.Write(textbox.Text);//Pronto, temos o valor do textbox que você quer.
                Response.Write(e.CommandArgument);//Em e.CommandArgument terá o valor de pes_codigo que vem da tabela pessoas.
            }

        }
    }
```

Obs.: Só acrescentei um `CausesValidation="False"` nos botões, para evitar problemas com validação.

Comment: Sim, até aí tudo bem, consigo pegar os valores que estão no CommandArgument. O problema é que no btnValidar_Command eu preciso pegar exatamente o valor preenchido no TextBox correspondente a este btnValidar, compreende? Suponhamos que eu tenha 5 TextBoxes, cada TextBox desses corresponde ao input de uma pessoa na aplicação e esses inputs serão feitos ao clicar no btnValidar. Exemplo: meu TextBox é o segundo, quando preencho o segundo TextBox e clico no btnValidar ele salva somente a informação que eu postei, deixando em aberto pros demais usuários.

Comment: Editei minha resposta, e inclui trecho para pegar o valor do TextBox preenchido.

Comment: Acabei de testar e não funcionou. Coloquei alguns breakpoints para verificar a execução do btnValidar_Command, mas ele nem sequer é disparado. Será que tem algo haver com o ciclo de vida das páginas em ASP.NET? Editei minha pergunta com os métodos que criei.

Comment: Desativei o CausesValidation no button, meu button ficou assim : `<asp:Button ID="btnValidar" CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "pes_codigo") %>' OnCommand="btnValidar_Command" CssClass="btn btn-default" runat="server" Text="Go!" CausesValidation="False" />`, se bem que pode ser melhor você incluir um ValidationGroup no botão para cada linha.

Comment: Deixei meu button exatamente igual ao seu e ainda assim não funcionou. O OnCommand continua não sendo disparado. Editei o button na pergunta.

Comment: Como está sendo feito o hook dos eventos? Na primeira linha de seu arquivo aspx, nas diretivas da página, verifique se você tem a propriedade `AutoEventWireup="true"` ?